# How to get details and facebook albums through django app in django-scoial-auth

Tags: python, django, facebook, django-views

I have followed the django-social-auth, i am able to login with facebook ID, but how to get the details,images that are stored in facebook into my django application using django-social-auth module.

Comment: django-social-auth is for login using credentials. You can use facebook graph api for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Please read this first:
http://www.tryolabs.com/Blog/2012/02/13/get-user-data-using-django-social-auth/

And then read read graph API on facebook:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/

All I have done so far is get a mugshot, but this was how I started.

Comment: Any example app on this regarding, so that we can understand better then we can get use of it. Other than user profile pic, can we get his album photos.                                                where should we write this funciton in views or any where else.                                                        def get_user_avatar(backend, details, response, social_user, uid,\
                    user, *args, **kwargs):

Comment: It seems you can. If you look at the first link the guys defines url as:  http://graph.facebook.com/%s/picture?type=large" % response['id'].    So he is supplying access token Id obtained from django social auth and passing it to facebook graph api. If you want to get albums you have to follow the url for obtaining albums which you can see in the second link. So basically , you can use a lot of stuff from the first link, and only change the url link to graph api. Facebook returns an array of images then.